# Как получить количество дней в пересечении 2х периодов?

Tags: java, алгоритм, функциональное-программирование

Например: я хочу сравнить 2 периода [1мая-15мая] и [5мая-30мая] мне нужно узнать количество дней, которые попадают и в 1ый период и во 2ой.

Причем дата 1 п1 и дата 2 п2 могут быть как в 1 день, так и раньше одна другой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `java` есть класс `java.time.Period` для хранения информации и временных промежутках. Он имеет следующий конструктор `Period.between(LocalDate start, LocalDate end)`.
В данной ситуации нужно лишь правильно определить дату начала и конца из четырех имеющихся дат. Напишем метод который это делает:

```
private static Period getPeriod(LocalDate s1, LocalDate f1, 
                                LocalDate s2, LocalDate f2) {
    //наиболее поздняя дата в качестве начала общего промежутка
    LocalDate start = s1.isAfter(s2) ? s1 : s2;
    //наиболее ранняя дата в качестве конечной даты
    LocalDate end = f1.isBefore(f2) ? f1 : f2;
    //ситуация когда пересечения у двух промежутков нет
    if ((start == s1 && end == f1) || (start == s2 && end == f2))
        return Period.ZERO;
    else
        return Period.between(start, end);
}
```

Использовать его можно следующим образом:

```
LocalDate s1 = LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 1);
LocalDate f1 = LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 5);

LocalDate s2 = LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 3);
LocalDate f2 = LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 10);

System.out.println(getPeriod(s1, f1, s2, f2).getDays());
```

Вывод:

> 2

Answer (score 2):

как диапазон берете максимальную дату из двух дат начала(в вашем примере 5 мая) и минимальную из двух дат окончания(в вашем примере 15 мая).

Вычитаете - получаете количество дней, которые пересекаются в первом и втором периоде

**P.S.**:Если нужен пример на `Java` как посчитать разницу между двумя `Date`, [вот](http://www.baeldung.com/java-date-difference) есть неплохое описание